# NPM Start isn't working (Can't get Node working on Mac OS X Yosemite)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, macos, npm

I'm a Rails guy, but I'm trying to learn a bit of Angular JS. I wanted to go through [this tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial), but I can't even get a node server to start running.

Below is the npm-debug.log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.7.4
3 info using node@v0.12.2
4 verbose config Skipping project config: /Users/piratetone/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose stack Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/piratetone/package.json'
5 verbose stack     at Error (native)
6 verbose cwd /Users/piratetone/js_projects
7 error Darwin 14.1.0
8 error argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
9 error node v0.12.2
10 error npm  v2.7.4
11 error path /Users/piratetone/package.json
12 error code ENOENT
13 error errno -2
14 error enoent ENOENT, open '/Users/piratetone/package.json'
14 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
14 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
15 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

Comment: Does `/usr/local/bin/npm` and/or `/Users/piratetone/package.json` exist?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/npm exists. It is not a directory though. package.json is NOT present though.

Comment: I think that you've found the main issue here.

Comment: How do I resolve this then? I create a package.json file? I tried "npm init" and it says the file was created, but when I check the directory, the file is not present

Comment: It must be creating it someplace else; check the log to see if it reveals the location, then try copying the file into `/Users/piratetone/`

Comment: Now the error looks to be - 5 verbose stack Error: missing script: start

Comment: You need to include a start script in `package.json`. Something like: `{"scripts": {"start": "node server.js"}}`

Comment: holy smokes. i'm putting this on hold for now. the tutorial makes it seem like i have to just plug in a full commands. i want to code, not set up my development box. i'm getting hundreds of "npm ERR!"s associated with Darwin 14.1.0 and more when I run npm start now... looks even sloppier. likely all directory permissions issues

Comment: I don't blame you — It's not as easy as 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm going to start completely over later tonight when I have some more time to tinker with this! Not giving up on node yet

Comment: Maybe do a tutorial specifically for setting up node on `OS X` then try the Angular stuff, you might have better results that way.

Comment: I got it to work! "sudo npm start" did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in [this tutorial here.](https://coderwall.com/p/cbacta/how-to-setup-your-mac-to-build-single-page-applications-with-angularjs-and-neo4j) Also, after getting everything completed there, I also needed sudo to install.

```
sudo npm start
```

Comment: Ahhh no , don't install node with sudo :)  That's bad practice.  You should be installing as your own user and setting the permissions (similar to how you should be doing in ruby :)  See this thread for some context - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo